# Error: This module requires Ninject.Web.WebAPI extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

I'm using Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost v3.2.4 and I get this error the first time you hit a page.  Then it works from then on:

> This module requires Ninject.Web.WebAPI extension

The stacktrace is:

> [InvalidOperationException: This module requires Ninject.Web.WebAPI extension]
>      Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost.OwinWebApiModule.VerifyRequiredModulesAreLoaded() +202
>      Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule.OnVerifyRequiredModules() +10
>      Ninject.KernelBase.Load(IEnumerable``1 m) +419
>      Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost.OwinBootstrapper.CreateKernel() +30
>      Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper.Initialize(Func`1 createKernelCallback) +16
>      Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost.d__1.MoveNext() +189
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>      Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__5.MoveNext() +187
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>      Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__2.MoveNext() +185
>      Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +69
>      Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +64
>      System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +380
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This occurs when you create your kernel without scanning the DLLs for Ninject modules, for example:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings
{
     LoadExtensions = false
});
```

The way to fix this is to manually load the modules that Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost needs

```
kernel.Load(typeof(Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebApiModule).Assembly);
```

Comment: My issue is a little bit different but your explanation helped me a lot to solve my issue... thank you so much!!!

Comment: `kernel.Load<WebApiModule>();` is more comfy.